File download from Javascript not working but OK from direct HTML link
I am trying to download a file from an ESP32 which is running the PsychicHTTP webserver. For testing, this is just a fixed .CSV file. In HTML:
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="saveFile()">Save file</button>
</div>

In the associated Javascript:
function saveFile() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log("SAVING FILE");
  xhr.open("GET", "/saveFile", true);
  xhr.send();
}

In the ESP32 code, in the setup for the webserver:
server.on("/saveFile", [](PsychicRequest *request) {
  Serial.println("SAVE FILE REQUEST");
  String filename = "/results/sample.csv";
  PsychicFileResponse response(request, LittleFS, filename, (String&)("text/csv"), true);

  return response.send();
});

I have also made a small mod to the PsychicHTTP webserver code to include "text/csv" as a MIME type.
When this is all running, the webserver receives the GET request for the download, I can see this in the Firefox console and in the ESP32 serial message. However the file doesn't download. ESP32 is at 192.168.0.136 so if I type in 192.168.0.136/saveFile directly in the browser address bar then the file is downloaded and saved.
I have seen a few different examples of file downloads in Javascript and they all seem to use either "FETCH" or some form of HTML. Something like this:


function downloadFile(url, fileName) {
  fetch(url, { method: 'get', mode: 'no-cors', referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer' })
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(res => {
      const aElement = document.createElement('a');
      aElement.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      const href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      aElement.href = href;
      aElement.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      aElement.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
    });
};



I can also try the simple HTML version of this when I get time - just using  tag with download attribute - as my requirement is pretty simple.
So my two questions:

Why does a direct addressing to the download link work from the address bar but the Javascript above does not work?
If I use the FETCH example below, do I retain the same code in the ESP32 to respond or is something different required?


mode: 'no-cors' you can’t do this if you want to use the response, docs

That was just an example I found of the FETCH API. My file is on the same ESP32 so there should be no CORS issues. In my case, looking at the Firefox console, I am getting Referrer-Policy of "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" if that is important.

I would expect your download file function to work correctly if you get rid of mode no cors, otherwise it will not work.

My current function is the one above - saveFile(). That's the one that doesn't seem to work. downloadFile is an example I found where somebody uses the FETCH API. I haven't tried it yet.

if url is not same origin, then the server needs to send CORS headers in the response, if you want to access the url from a browser. Alternatively, don't use fetch (or XMLHttpRequest) just use window.location=url and if the content-type in the response is set to text/csv (which is implied by the code you've shown), your browser should offer to save the result as a downloaded file

XHR will not do a download to Download folder. it can return the content of the file to process it in javascript. the browser will not allow to save a file by script..

So to be clear, you are currently using the first JS snippet (ie with XMLHttpRequest)? You are aware, you have to react on some events of your request once you sent it? The most important being the load event?

This question is similar to: Prompt file download with XMLHttpRequest. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Maybe not the full answer but I ended up just using the download attribute of the anchor tag. I can use a JS function to set the filename to whatever I need. There are no CORS issues to maange.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
